# Accessing parent isolated scope in directive

Tags: javascript, html, angular.js

I was looking for a way to markup parts of my app as restricted to only certain roles, on an element basis.

This works quite well, using an attribute directive, where I specify the allowed roles and disable/hide the corresponding element; e.g.

```
<input require-role="admin" />
```

In order to make the app more maintainable I thought about inheriting the the required role attribute, e.g.

```
<form>
    <div required-role="Admin">              <!-- Set:       'Admin' -->
        <input required-role/>               <!-- Inherit:   'Admin' -->
        <input required-role/>               <!-- Inherit:   'Admin' -->
        <input required-role/>               <!-- Inherit:   'Admin' -->
        <input required-role/>               <!-- Inherit:   'Admin' -->
        <input />                            <!-- No role checking  -->
        <div required-role="User">           <!-- Overwrite: 'User' -->
            <input required-role/>           <!-- Inherit:   'User' -->
        </div>
    </div>                                 
    <div required-role="Admin User">         <!-- Set:   'Admin User' -->         
        <input required-role/>               <!-- Inherit:   'Admin User' -->
        <input required-role/>               <!-- Inherit:   'Admin User' -->
        <input required-role/>               <!-- Inherit:   'Admin User' -->
        <input required-role="Admin"/>       <!-- Overwrite: 'Admin' -->
    </div>
    <button required-role="Admin">Save</button>
    <button required-role="User">Send to review</button>
</form>
```

What I came up with is the following directive, that recursively searches in the `isolatedScope` of the `parent` element until it eventually finds the `requiredRole` property:

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope){
  $scope.name = 'World';
});
app.directive('requireRole', function(){
  var getRequiredRoleFromParent = function(element){
    var par = element.parent();
    if (!par) return;
    var is = par.isolateScope();
    if (is && is.requireRole) return is.requireRole;
    return getRequiredRoleFromParent(par);
  };
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    scope   : {
      requireRole: '@'
    },
    link    : function(scope, element){
      var labelClass = "label-success";
      if (!scope.requireRole) {
        scope.requireRole = getRequiredRoleFromParent(element);
        labelClass = "label-info";
      }
      element.prepend('<span class="label ' + labelClass + ' ">' + scope.requireRole + '</span>');
    }
  }
});
```

I am happy with the solution I came up with, yet my experience developing directives is limited; maybe there are better ways to achieve the same behavior?

Plunkr can be found [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/rbtTRsuPVPCKJVf8GGA7)

Answer (score 1):

In your HTML

> ```
>   <form>
>       <div required-role="Admin">              <!-- Set:       'Admin' -->
>           <input required-role/>               <!-- Inherit:   'Admin' -->
>           <input required-role/>               <!-- Inherit:   'Admin' -->
>           <input required-role/>               <!-- Inherit:   'Admin' -->
>           <input required-role/>               <!-- Inherit:   'Admin' -->
>           <input />                            <!-- No role checking  -->
>           <div required-role="User">           <!-- Overwrite: 'User' -->
>               <input required-role/>           <!-- Inherit:   'User' -->
>           </div>
>       </div>                                 
>       <div required-role="Admin User">         <!-- Set:   'Admin User' -->         
>           <input required-role/>               <!-- Inherit:   'Admin User' -->
>           <input required-role/>               <!-- Inherit:   'Admin User' -->
>           <input required-role/>               <!-- Inherit:   'Admin User' -->
>           <input required-role="Admin"/>       <!-- Overwrite: 'Admin' -->
>       </div>
>       <button required-role="Admin">Save</button>
>       <button required-role="User">Send to review</button>
>   </form>
> ```

You create a `div` just to inherit from it, this is bad practice, unless there is more than one element inside that `div` that is going to inherit from the `div`

in the second group of code you actually do it the right way, not sure why you were inconsistent with the first block.

you should write it like this

```
<form>
    <div required-role="Admin">              <!-- Set:       'Admin' -->
        <input required-role/>               <!-- Inherit:   'Admin' -->
        <input required-role/>               <!-- Inherit:   'Admin' -->
        <input required-role/>               <!-- Inherit:   'Admin' -->
        <input required-role/>               <!-- Inherit:   'Admin' -->
        <input />                            <!-- No role checking  -->
        <input required-role="User"/>        <!-- Inherit:   'User' -->
    </div>                                 
    <div required-role="Admin User">         <!-- Set:   'Admin User' -->         
        <input required-role/>               <!-- Inherit:   'Admin User' -->
        <input required-role/>               <!-- Inherit:   'Admin User' -->
        <input required-role/>               <!-- Inherit:   'Admin User' -->
        <input required-role="Admin"/>       <!-- Overwrite: 'Admin' -->
    </div>
    <button required-role="Admin">Save</button>
    <button required-role="User">Send to review</button>
</form>
```

I also assume that this is Example HTML as you don't give any of those `input` tags `ID`'s  which makes them unusable.

---

In your Javascript

> ```
>   var getRequiredRoleFromParent = function(element){
>       var par = element.parent();
>       if (!par) return;
>       var is = par.isolateScope();
>       if (is && is.requireRole) return is.requireRole;
>       return getRequiredRoleFromParent(par);
>   };
> ```

You could take the negative check out of there, it doesn't make sense that way, instead perform a positive check, if it's true then you can perform what is after that.

The "after that" stuff should be changed to a ternary statement, it looks cleaner to me and it is equivalent.  It is slightly nested but it shows the flow of the code brightly.

```
var getRequiredRoleFromParent = function(element){
    var par = element.parent();
    if (par) {
        var is = par.isolateScope();
        return (is && is.requireRole)
            ? is.requireRole
            : getRequiredRoleFromParent(par);
    }
};
```

The Recursion of this function looks good, I don't see an issue with the recursive nature of this function.

Comment: Your answer seems not particuliary useful to me. The HTML is obviously a SSCCE, there is no point in criticizing this minor point, in the real HTML there will obviously be more elements. Also, copying the whole HTML chunk adds nothing as it is already visible in the question itself.

Comment: The `!par` statement is even wrong to me, as exiting early and not using potentially nested ifs is good coding practice imho (see https://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/118703/where-did-the-notion-of-one-return-only-come-from). Also, the ternary statement is largely only a personal opinion, I don't think it is any easier to read.

Comment: Instead of such detailed critique about simple code styles, I am sure the OP is more looking for reviews if the approach (looking for the parent recursively for each element) is suitable in an AngularJS logic.

Comment: the `!par` is an extra statement that doesn't need to be run, my code does the same thing, `if (par) do stuff else nothing` OPs `if (!par) do nothing else do stuff`

Comment: Doing `if(par)` or `if(!par)` does not have any effect in terms of computation on most architectures. Even if if would, it would be totally negligible.

Comment: coding standards on the other hand say that you should write a clear path and not dance around the fire 3 times before doing what needs to be done. if you would like to discuss further we can take this to chat. [2nd Monitor](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8595/the-2nd-monitor)

Comment: @dirkk In addition to what Malachi said, I'd like to add, that codereviews (especially stylistic recommendations) are **always** at least slightly opinionated. Why not write your own competing answer?

Comment: @Vogel612 Because the OP is a colleague of mine and we discussed the issue before posting here. If I would now better, it would already be included in the question. However, my point is that we are really not so much interested in stylistic advise, but instead a review if this bottom-to-top recursive approach makes sense in an AngularJS environment.

Comment: @dirkk I would **love** if you'd take a [tour] and read our [help/on-topic]. Please be aware the latter explicitly mentions: **"Reviewers may comment on any part of the code"** Your criticism of this answer thus is IMO unjustified and slightly rude. Aside from that, further discussion should be taken to [chat] or [meta] ;)

Comment: Thanks everyone for taking care of this question. I was indeed more interested in AngularJS specifics :-) But nevertheless, the issues you mentioned with my example code are valid, thank you.